# 2 data list comparaisons Haskell

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I have 2 data lists in haskell each which contain an id attribut. I would like to compare both lists and return all data objects from that are in the first list but not the second.

### Here is an example:

```
type IDLibrary = Int
type Location = String
type Author = String

data Book = Book IDLibrary Author deriving Show
data Library = LibraryBook IDLibrary Location deriving Show

book1 = Book 1 "Anthony C"
library1 = LibraryBook 2 "Alaska"
listB :: [Book]
listB = [book1]
listL :: [Library]
listL = [library1]
```

Comment: Can you add a bit of code that makes it more explicit what these lists contain?

Comment: Yes of course !

Comment: type idLibrary = Int
type location = String
type author = String


data Book = Book idLibrary author deriving Show
data Library = Book idLibrary location deriving Show

Book1 = (Book 1 "Anthony C")
Library1 = (Library 2 "Alaska")

listB :: [Book]
listB = [Book1]

listL :: [Library]
listL = [Library1]

Comment: this is not valid haskell code

Comment: Sorry please remove i7 line

Comment: @EraseMe You should be able to edit the question (I think some of the types need to have a capital first letter as well for it be valid)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `intersectBy` and `\\` from `Data.List`.

With `intersectBy` You would create list of common elements, and then use `\\` to remove those for Your list.

Mathematical term for desired outcome is relative complement of one set in another, so that's how I will call main function.

**Note: I defined *Eq* instance for *Book* where equality means equality of id's but that's only for the benefit of *elem*. If that definition do not meet Your needs then replace *elem* use in remove with something that check for ids there.**

***import Data.List* is only for *intersectBy* function**

```
import Data.List

type IDLibrary = Int
type Location = String
type Author = String

data Book = Book IDLibrary Author deriving Show
data Library = LibraryBook IDLibrary Location deriving Show

instance Eq Book where
  (==) (Book id _) (Book id' _) = id == id'

listB :: [Book]
listB = [Book 1 "Anthony C", Book 3 "David Weber"]
listL :: [Library]
listL = [LibraryBook 1 "Alaska", LibraryBook 2 "Majorka"]

relativeComplement :: [Book] -> [Library] -> [Book]
relativeComplement xs ys = xs `remove` common xs ys

remove :: [Book] -> [Book] -> [Book]
remove xs ys = filter (not . (`elem` ys)) xs

common :: [Book] -> [Library] -> [Book]
common xs ys = intersectBy sameID xs (intoBooks ys)

sameID :: Book -> Book -> Bool
sameID (Book id1 _) (Book id2 _) = id1 == id2

intoBooks :: [Library] -> [Book]
intoBooks = map turnIntoBook
          where turnIntoBook (LibraryBook id _) = Book id ""
```

Output:

> [Book 3 "David Weber"]

PS By no means my code is of high quality, I too am in a process of learning Haskell.

Comment: Could you provide an example?